# django: How DetailView work for two model or how class-based-views work for two model?

Tags: python, django

I planing to write a blog with Django.In my blog page,I want to show Blog and Comment,I tried to use DetailView

```
class BlogDetailView(DetailView):

    template_name = 'inventory/item_detail.html'
    model = Blogitem

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        pk = self.kwargs.get('id')
        try:
            item = Blogitem.objects.get(pk=pk)
            item.view_number = item.view_number + 1
            item.save()
            comment_list  = Comment.objects.filter(comment_blog_id=pk).order_by(F('comment_date').asc())
            context['item'] = item
            context['comment_list'] = comment_list
        except Blogitem.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
        return context
```

**error**:Generic detail view BlogDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug..

I know I need to add codes like `model = somethings` or get queryset by using`get_queryset(self):`  below `template_name = 'inventory/item_detail.html'`

if I add the line(⇩⇩⇩) below `template_name = 'inventory/item_detail.html'`

```
model = Blogitem, Comment
```

I GET 
**error**:'tuple' object has no attribute '_default_manager'

**urls.py**

`url(r'^blog/(?P<id>(\d+))/$',views.BlogDetailView.as_view() , name='item_detail')`

**models.py**

```
class Blogitem(models.Model):
    title            = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content_html     = models.TextField() #html
    content_markdown = models.TextField() #markdown
    publication_date = models.DateTimeField()
    update_date      = models.DateTimeField()
    first_tag        = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                                        default= 'other') 
    tag_supplement   = models.CharField(max_length=100) #tag supplement
    view_number      = models.IntegerField()
def __str__(self):
    return (u'%s %s') %(self.title,self.publication_date)

class Admin:
    pass

class Meta:
    ordering = ['publication_date']
    verbose_name_plural = verbose_name = 'blog'




class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_blog = models.ForeignKey(Blogitem, verbose_name=u'blog')
    comment_user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, verbose_name= u'user',blank= True,null = True)
    comment_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=u'comment date',auto_now = True)
    comment_content = models.TextField(verbose_name=u'comment words')
    comment_approved = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=u'comment approved',default= True)
    comment_like = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=u'like number',default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return (u'%s %s %s %s') % (self.comment_blog, self.comment_user, self.comment_content, self.comment_date)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-comment_date']
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name = 'comment'
```

I know I can fix the bug with function-based-view but not class-based-views:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^blog/(?P<id>(\d+))/$',views.item_detail , name='item_detail')
```

**views.py**

```
def item_detail(request, id):
    '''
    detail of blog
    '''
    try:
        item = Blogitem.objects.get(id=id)
        item.view_number = item.view_number + 1
        item.save()
        comment_list  = Comment.objects.filter(comment_blog_id=item.id).order_by(F('comment_date').asc())
    except Blogitem.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    return render_to_response( 'inventory/item_detail.html', {'item': item,'comment_list': comment_list}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**How DetailView work for two model or how can I use class-based-views to work for two model?**

Comment: `model = BlogItem`. You must put the model you are displaying details of.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify your `model` in Detail View. and add comments_list in `get_context_data`

```
class BlogDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Blogitem
    template_name = 'inventory/item_detail.html'
    slug_field = 'pk'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comment_list']  = Comment.objects.filter(comment_blog_id=pk).order_by(F('comment_date').asc())
        # other code
        return context
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^blog/(?P<pk>(\d+))/$',views.BlogDetailView.as_view() , name='item_detail')
```

Comment: It can't work,**error**:AttributeError at /blog/8/,Generic detail view BlogDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.Exception Location: /myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py in get_object, line 49

Comment: @TaylorLively try removing `id` and add `pk` (?P<pk>[^/]+) in urls.

Comment: It takes me sometime to change template.it's ok!Thank you!

Comment: @MicroPyramid I know this is old, but did you mean `filter(id=self.slug_field)`?  You don't define `pk` anywhere in the class.